# Print out HTTPHeaders to log file on ASMX / WCF Calls using config settings

Tags: .net, web-services, http-headers, trace

I have some web services already running on a few environments, and some developers are needing to get the raw HTTPHeaders that are being sent to these web services. These services are set up using HTTPS.

I can't use wireshark/fiddler to intercept the data, one it's encrypted, and two there are too many SSL rules needed for fiddler it kind of bombs.

I "could" code it, but I'm looking for a way I could modify the web.config to output all the data from these calls.

Thoughts?

I have:

```
 <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
        <source name="System.Web.Services.Asmx">
            <listeners>
                <add name="AsmxTraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="local.log" traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId, Callstack" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
        <add name="System.Web.Services.Asmx" value="Verbose"  />        
    </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

But that is not printing out HTTP Header information, or any type of SOAP data.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.Net" tracemode="protocolonly" maxdatasize="1024">
            <listeners>
                <add name="System.Net"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
        <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add 
            name="System.Net"
            type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
            initializeData="network.log"
        />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
</system.diagnostics>
```